# What is the exact meaning of this ViewBag setting into a .NET Razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

I am very new in **.NET** (I came from Java and Spring framework) and I have the following doubt about Razor pages.

I have a very simple page like this:

```
@model Vidly.Models.Customer

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Name;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
```

the first line declare the model object used by this page having type **Vidly.Models.Customer** (it contains the data used into the view), infact I access and show the value of the **Vidly.Models.Customer.Name** property by:

```
<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
```

My doubt is related to this section of the previous code:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Name;
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

What is it exactly doing?

I think that it is declaring some kind of object containing 2 properties that represent something like the settings of this view page (correct me if I am doing wrong assertion).

By this line it is declaring what is the page layout:

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
```

But what exactly means this line:

```
ViewBag.Title = Model.Name;
```

What is the **ViewBag**? and what means this setting? Model.Name should contain the value of the **Name** property inside the passed model object. What is exactly doing?

Comment: Find the `_Layout.cshtml` and see what is in the head tag. could be that is it using the view bag to set page title

Comment: What is view bag has also been answered many times https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209201/what-is-inside-viewbag

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: In general it is used for passing small amounts of data among controllers and views

Comment: Btw, since none of the answers address this, the syntax `@{ ... Stuff here... }` doesn't define an object, but instead a section of c# code. You can define variables, set properties, call methods, etc without having to prefix each line with the Razor `@` (in fact, there are things you can't do without this syntax, such as declaring or assigning a variable)

Comment: Possible duplicates of [What is inside ViewBag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209201/what-is-inside-viewbag) and [What is ViewBag.Title in Razor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354004/what-is-viewbag-title-in-razor).

Answer (score 0):

In general it is used for passing small amounts of data among controllers and views.

In the above example is it most likely setting the `title` of the page which is usually in the `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<title>My Page - @ViewBag.Title</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC there are three ways - ViewData, ViewBag and TempData to pass data from controller to view.

What is the ViewBag?

- ViewBag can be used to transfer data from the controller to the view, mostly temporary data.
- The ViewBag's exist only with the http request. It will be destroyed on redirection.
- ViewBag is a property of ControllerBase class.

What exactly means this line:

```
ViewBag.Title = Model.Name;
```

ViewBag can be more convenient to work with, since it doesn't require casting. You are setting the title using ViewBag. Since the ViewBag derives from DynamicViewData, this means that can allows the creation of dynamic properties using dot notation `@ViewBag.SomeKey = <value or object>`.

> Note: ViewBag isn't available in Razor Pages.